# add a prefix with df name in a loop through elements of list

Tags: loops, prefix

I have many data frames of stock indices. Each has a price column
Here is an simple example

```
    index1 <- c(2,3,5)
    colnames(index1) <- "price"
    index2 <- c(3,5,6)
    colnames(index2) <- "price"
```

I put them in a list and I want to create their log return with the index name as the prefix. I can only create the log return column with:

```
indexList <- list(index1,index2)
indexList <- lapply(indexList, function(i) {
  i <- i %>% mutate(log.ret = c(diff(log(price)),NA))
} )
```

What I want is

```
index1.log.ret
index2.log.ret
```